# Correct way to detect '/proc' file system?

Tags: linux, shell, unix, procfs

I'm writing a cross platform bash script. It needs to use this command #1:

```
cat /proc/$PID/cmdline
```

and if the procfs is not available (on OS X for example), it needs to fallback to this command #2:

```
ps -eo "pid command" | grep "^$PID"
```

My question is pretty simple: what is the correct way to detect if '/proc' file system exists?

Comment: For what it's worth, `ps -o command= -p $PID` will give you what you want without the half-anchored _grep_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "proc filesystem" will almost always be mounted in `/proc` if present, but this does not have to be the case always (at least in theory). Probably a more portable way is to use `mount -t proc` to list mounted filesystems of type `proc` and extract the path from there. If the command returns no paths, `procfs` is not mounted and you can fall back to the alternative command.

Something along the lines of:

```
PROC_PATH=$(mount -t proc | egrep -o '/[^ ]+')
if [ "$PROC_PATH" ]; then
    # use procfs
else
    # use alternative
fi
```

On the other hand, `ps` should be more portable and always work, so maybe best solutions is just to use `ps` always?

Answer (score 0):

Proc filesystem is mounted on /proc.

```
mount | awk '/proc/ {print $3}'       This will show all mounted proc filesystems with full path
```